# Atom feed and rss reader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feed, atom-feed

I'm trying to add a Atom feed for a page, but it just keeps spinning and adds all the items if only one new was added. What am i doing wrong?

http://legionaere.de/posts.atom?team_slug=1_team

[image]

I'm using the default atom_feed helper from rails3

Comment: did you try the solution I gave below ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add the pubDate entry similar to the published:

And also the format of the dates.

for example:

```
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title("Posts")
  feed.pubDate(CGI.rfc1123_date(@posts.first.created_at))
  feed.published(CGI.rfc1123_date(@posts.first.created_at))
  feed.updated(CGI.rfc1123_date(@posts.first.created_at))

  @posts.each do |post|
    feed.entry(:url => post_path(post)) do |entry|
      entry.title(post.title)
      entry.pubDate(CGI.rfc1123_date(post.created_at))
      entry.published(CGI.rfc1123_date(post.created_at))
      entry.updated(CGI.rfc1123_date(post.created_at))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: yes additional pubDate field in the feed and entry did the trick, published and updated can be ignored since they come right out of the box. thx